# Integrating Dynamic PHP/SQL Dynamic Sub Menus with CSS

Tags: php, html, css

Actual Image of the table:
[image: **PHP MySQL Table Image**]

Here's my "menu.php" content wherein I'm looping my Parent & Sub Categories together.

```
<?php

function loop_array($array = array(), $parentID = 0) {
    if (!empty($array[$parentID])) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($array[$parentID] as $items) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo $items['categoryName'];
            loop_array($array, $items['categoryID']);
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}

function display_menus() {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "submenu");
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM category");
    $array = array();

    if (mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $array[$rows['parentID']][] = $rows;
        }
        loop_array($array);
    }
}
```

And, here's my "index.php" where I'm calling the "display_menus()" function to display all the categories and sub categories from this  [**SQL TABLE.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVsQQ.png)

```html
 <?php require 'menu.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sub Menu Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      display_menus();
    ?> 
  </body>
</html>
```

After connecting these two PHP pages. I'm getting this result exact result:
[image: " **Image result in Web Browser** "]

Lastly, My problem is. How do I integrate this with CSS? That will look like a navigation menu with sub menus. I tried different tutorials in YouTube but I failed. Is there any CSS Menu Builder or other sources that has compatibility with this code? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For integrating CSS with HTML (any element), you need to add a CSS file to your HTML file.

Need to add classes, ids selectors to your elements.

And add definitions to those classes, ids.

For example (inline stylesheet):

```
<style>
.left { /* Class for left aligned elements*/
 float: left; /* This is attribute to be modified*/
}
#page-header { /* For element with id page-header*/
 font-weight: bold; /* This is attribute to be modified*/
}
</style>

in HTML,

<div id="page-header">Welcome to StackOverflow</div>
<div class="left">Tips to ask Questions on SO</div>
<ul class="left">
<li>Search on Google for your problem</li>
<li>Don't put why this code doesn't work on Question</li>
</ul>
```

**Also, Back to your question, for menus, we can use [suprefish](https://superfish.joelbirch.co/examples/) library.**

Comment: Yes. I forgot to post my CSS code and its results. Please refer to my answer below. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello. Are you still there?

Comment: Hi, how can I help you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my CSS content where I'm calling it in my `index.php` as

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <?php
　　　　　display_menus();
    ?>
```

and changed my `menu.php` function loop_aray into:

```
function loop_array($array = array(), $parentID = 0){

        if(!empty($array[$parentID])){
            echo '<ul class="cssmenu">';
            foreach($array[$parentID] as $items){
            echo '<li class="has-sub">';
            echo $items['categoryName'];
            loop_array($array, $items['categoryID']);
            echo '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
```

This is what I'm [**GETTING**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VcId.png) and this is what I want as the [**OUTPUT**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z00Hx.png).

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300);
#cssmenu {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  width: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ece6e8;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d9ced2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -o-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
#cssmenu > ul li#responsive-tab {
  display: none;
  /* Hide for large screens */

}
#cssmenu > ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ece6e8;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d9ced2;
  border-top: 0 none;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a {
  background-image: url('images/caret.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 90% -95%;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a.active,
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a:hover {
  background: #d80041 url('images/caret.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: 90% 195%;
}
#cssmenu > ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px 11px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #747474;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul li a.active,
#cssmenu > ul li a:hover {
  background: #d80041;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #cssmenu > ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li#responsive-tab {
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li#responsive-tab a {
    background: url('images/menu.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% -35%;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li#responsive-tab a:hover {
    background-color: #d80041;
    background-position: 95% 135%;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.right {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub {
    position: relative;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 0 none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li {
    display: block !important;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li a span {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 24px;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a {
    background-image: none;
  }
}
/* Make sure they show even if hidden in mobile view by JS */
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  #cssmenu > ul > li.collapsed {
    display: inline-block !important;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul ul li.collapsed {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```